# JSDoc - Documenting a mixed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, documentation, jsdoc

In JSDoc, how to document an array accepting multiple object class like this:

```
var arr = [new Foo(), new Bar()];
```

How to write the type such that `Foo` and `Bar` are the only class that are accepted in the array?

Comment: Is this the correct way?
`/** @type {[Foo|Bar]} */`

Comment: I believe that you are looking for `{Array.<Foo|Bar>}`

Comment: Another option is `{(Foo|Bar)[]}`

Comment: @KevinLaw `[Foo|Bar]` would mean a one element tuple where the first/only element is `Foo` or `Bar`.

Answer (score 14):

If the type of the first object should always be `Foo` and the second always `Bar`, we're looking at what would be understood as a tuple object. In this case, the correct JSDoc type would be:

```
/** @type {[Foo, Bar]} */
const arr = [new Foo(), new Bar()];
```

And not `Array<Foo|Bar>` as one could've thought, since the latter allows for things like `[new Foo(), new Foo()]`, which is probably undesired.

Comment: in `jsdoc` 3.6.3 (and I assume all earlier versions), this syntax is illegal and throws an error

Comment: Is there any official documentation about this JSDoc notation? See https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/issues/495#issuecomment-590636289

Comment: I am afraid that `[Foo, Bar]` is used for tuples. I.e. a tuple with exactly two elements where the first one is `Foo` and the second `Bar`.
A general array that can have multiple Foos and Bars will be `(Foo|Bar)[]` as @austin_ce suggested.

Comment: You are correct, @dannymo. If you read my answer carefully, you'll see that it presupposes a tuple with predetermined types for each position. For an array where types can be at any position, austin_ce's suggestion is correct indeed.

Comment: Its 2022 and this syntax is still illegal.  Whilst vscode can handle this syntax, the `jsdoc` CLI cannot.